# Trying to resize an image using PHP

Tags: php

Anybody know what's wrong with this code? Instead of giving me an actual image, it's giving me an image error. I think I set all the functions correctly and everything. Any suggestions would be awesome.

```
<?php
function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height) {
  list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

  $width = $orig_width;
  $height = $orig_height;

  # taller
  if ($height > $max_height) {
    $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
    $height = $max_height;
  }

  # wider
  if ($width > $max_width) {
    $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
    $width = $max_width;
  }

  $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

  $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

  imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

  return $image_p;
}

$directory = "uploads/";
$images = glob($directory."*");

foreach($images as $image) {

  // Set a maximum height and width
  $width = 200;
  $height = 200;
  $newImage = resizeImage($image, $width, $height);

  echo '<img src="'.$newImage.'" /><br />';
}      
?>
```

Comment: oh do I have to save resized images some where?

Comment: if you have to show only one image then you need not. but here you are showing multiple images in same page.

Comment: @JaeKim : If you don't want to save the images, then check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont want to save the image, then you can use the below code.

```
<?php
    function resizeImage($filename, $max_width, $max_height) {
        list($orig_width, $orig_height) = getimagesize($filename);

        $width = $orig_width;
        $height = $orig_height;

        # taller
        if ($height > $max_height) {
            $width = ($max_height / $height) * $width;
            $height = $max_height;
        }

        # wider
        if ($width > $max_width) {
            $height = ($max_width / $width) * $height;
            $width = $max_width;
        }

        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($image_p); 
        $imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
        return $imgSrc;
    }

    $directory = "uploads/";
    $images = glob($directory."*");

    foreach($images as $image) {
        // Set a maximum height and width
        $width = 200;
        $height = 200;
        $imgSrc = resizeImage($image, $width, $height);
        echo '<img src="'.$imgSrc.'" /><br />';
    }      
?>
```

if you want to save the image, then you have to create some other folder like `resized` and save cropped images there and link it as given below.(don't change your old code and add this)

```
<?php    
    $directory = "uploads/";
    $images = glob($directory."*");

    $i=1;//added
    foreach($images as $image) {
       // Set a maximum height and width
        $width = 200;
        $height = 200;
        $newImage = resizeImage($image, $width, $height);
        imagejpeg($newImage,"resized/newimage".$i.".jpg");  //added
        echo '<img src="resized/newimage'.$i.'.jpg" /><br />';//modified
        $i++;//added
    }      
?>
```

Comment: `$imgSrc = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(ob_get_clean());` will this work??

Comment: yes it gets the current buffer contents and delete current output buffer.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php